# security warning while try to open local links from pdf file in evince

Tags: fedora, security, pdf

After updating to fedora 33 I cannot open links from a pdf file which are pointing into my local file system.

> ** (evince:4693): WARNING **: 20:22:47.413: Security alert: this document has been prevented from opening the file “some/file/name.jpg"

The links in the file are valid and pointing to the correct file. The file is created via pdflatex and is intended to be a link list for my personal use.

How can I allow the access in general or for that special file?

Comment: Can you post your update and the solution as answer?

Comment: Please don't post answers as edits to your question. Someone else has taken your edit and posted it as an answer, which is a good thing because that way the question can be marked as answered. Yes, they should have provided clear attribution, but that has now been done. If you want to post an answer yourself, that would be great! But please post it as an _answer_ and not an edit. Feel free to flag the other answer for removal after you post your own.

Comment: I'll be happy to remove my answer if the original poster wishes to post his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT related to a security alert as the warning tells us! The feature "open a external link" is simply intentional removed from evince with the last changes they did. The given warning is totally wrong, it is definitely not that the "this document...", it is simply that they drop the code for open links.

I found the broken patch: e85a79a355ff40149669611812695aad87a1af8d

But it is impossible to build evince on my host, as building is related to gnome-builder. The gnome builder works but the build fails with millions of error messages. In a short: No chance to build gnome tools on a standard installation without being an exorcist. Why we don't have configure/make/install??? This gnome-builder gui is a nightmare!

OK, searching for other pdf viewers:

- okular: This now displays external linked images inside the tool itself. This may help, but not in my case as I link to the first picture I search for.
- firefox: did not open external links from pdf
- gv: did not help as it misses so many features, it simply can't link to file local refs
- mupdf: Yepp! This is the only tool which is currently working for me!

All this ends up for me in the consequence that I have to stop using pdf at all. If opening a link is blamed as a security issue, we should stop using html :-) I have no idea why such changes have a chance to be committed. Ok, our company now moves to html for all documents. That`s make the world not simpler nor saver.

Comment: I feel the same. The patch removing PDF standard links has broken the experience of using Latex Beamer for my presentations.
https://twitter.com/ax5/status/1631433094296117249

Comment: This is stressful. I have to give my lecture tomorrow morning and Ubuntu's "Document Viewer" stopped following links just today...

Comment: Not sure my and your problem have the same source but in my case I could fix it by removing an old fix : I used to use \href{run:./file.html} in my LaTeX source instead of \href{./file.html} because the second one would not work. Now it is the first one that does not work but the second one works again...

Answer (score 0):

The OP provided an answer as part of their question, so I am reproducing it below:

> This is NOT related to a security alert as the warning tells us! The feature "open a external link" is simply intentional removed from evince with the last changes they did. The given warning is totally wrong, it is definitely not that the "this document...", it is simply that they drop the code for open links.